# Writing an array of images

Tags: arrays, image, matlab, image-processing

I want to create an array of images in MATLAB (images in 2D `uint8` array form). I want to use them for writing .jpg files, or for `imshow` (Basically accessing each 2D from a 3D integer array). I am not able to use them for either purpose. Please help.
Here's a sample code:

```
for k =1:no_images
    for i=1:Height
        for j=1:Width
            image(k,i,j) = uint8( k+i+j ) ;
        end
    end
    imshow( image(k) );
end
```

Answer (score 2):

This will to the job.

```
Img = image(k,:,:);
imshow(Img);
```

**EDIT**

As a 3D array like this, you only have grayscale image, but if you have a 4D array that contain your color channel it's the same.

```
Img = image(k,:,:,:);
imshow(Img);
```

**EDIT2**

Before the image your image is `1xHeightxWidth`, so you just need to do

```
Img = reshape(Img,[Height Width]);
```

Comment: I have tried using this. Does not work :(
Error is: Error using imageDisplayValidateParams>validateCData (line 117)
Unsupported dimension.

Comment: What this does is: size(Img) is 1 256 256

Also, Img(1) is 64 when I print it

Comment: You need to do Img = reshape(Img,[Height Width]); , sorry I miss that

Comment: @Maggie Try `Img = squeze(image(k,:,:))`

Comment: @Maggie Or better yet use _last_ index to refer to each image: `Img = image(:,:,k)`

Comment: Luis Mendo is right, Last index will be more intuitive if someone have to work/read your code.

Comment: @Maggie, Also, you shouldn't use `image` as a variable name. `image` is a Matlab function

Comment: One more unrelated problem I am facing:
  Img =  squeeze(reduced_image(k,:,:)) ;
imshow(Img);
The array is correct in Img, but when I use imshow in it, it shows a completey blank image. Any idea what did I do wrong?

Comment: For me, your code work well. It a gradient black-white left-top to right-bottom.

Comment: Yeah, the previous part now works fine.
I cant figure out the latter problem though :(

Answer (score 1):

You probably mean that you want to preallocate memory for these images, because `imshow` only presents them , and   `image(k,i,j) = uint8( k+i+j )`  just writes a number into each pixel of the 3D array accorsing to the loop (doesn't make sense)

just use

```
 image=zeros(N,M,L,'uint8');
```

where N,M,L are the 3-D dimensions, to create a 3D array of zeros. then `image(:,:,n)=...` will assign the n-th image into the array.

Comment: Nopes. I used the image(k,i,j) = uint8( k+i+j ) part to just give an example where i am processing the pixels of a preaallocated 3D array representing multiple image pixels.

Answer (score 1):

this may help:

```
img = cell(m, n);
img{i, j} = Image;
```